# Internal HD not detected via IDE/SATA usb on Vista

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

I was viewing some files from my old hard drive taken from an XP machine, on a Vista machine via a IDE/SATA usb cable and accidentally dropped the hard drive (about from a knee height), which landed on carpet.

Now my PC does not even detect the hard drive via the usb.

I went and got a new IDE/SATA usb cable thinking that might have fractured but It too does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's face it, it sounds like you just simply broke it. If the data is valuable enough, you can try buying a duplicate drive, and swapping the logic board, but otherwise you would probably need a professional data recovery firm with a clean room and significant expertise (costs a lot).